# Bootstrap table with form input doesn't shrink

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make an editable table with bootstrap.
So, it must include some inputs.
Table columns width usually fit with its content. Bootstrap's `form-control` sets the `width: 100%`, but i feel it too large and want the input smaller.

I found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388385/bootstrap-responsive-table-with-form-input-min-width) that i can use `w-auto` on my input to bypass this.
However, table doesn't seem to shrink the column size to it's content when i do this.

I guess i should somehow tell the table which column must expand to fill the space.
I've tried setting `w-100` to another column, but it breaks another `input-group` in another column.

```
<table class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <th>Problematic column</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td class="table-danger"><input type="number" class="form-control w-auto"></td>
    <td>Something else</td>
    <td>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">X</button>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[See plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4iLJqgFszaH4iYYo?preview)

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what u exactly want to achieve, but i think you want this behaviour?

Add `input-group` div around your first input field and remove the `w-auto` class.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-sm">
      <thead>
        <th>Problematic column</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td class="table-danger">
          <div class="input-group">
             <input type="number" class="form-control">
           </div>
        </td>
        <td>Something else</td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">X</button>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```